# Resize and convert images with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, file, image-resizing

I have some problems with my following code. I've got a task to develop a PHP program that can upload an image, then convert it to jpg and resize it to max width 300px or height 300px. The aspect ratio should be the same as the original one.

The strangest thing is, that the function "convertImage" output something like that:

```
����JFIF�����'�1�y�^�>�9<���H��^_������|6��a����B�����|%��^#��r�R:,������\z��c����='}U���S�s��$�bO�_��O$"���N74�����tл��ao/�8ԑ�G'�04���'��O�C��7��c1�99#8�׾}y�|�y�������3]ּg��G�t����Q��1x_����v��|8�n��^x�:mγ��[��iQ\>��]*���ĺ��-t{[��d��<-~x[���$���c������q�qӌ���d��=B9�3�<�y�;�I�תx��w�o�����~!|'��������T�7��U����~����ׇ͍5�J��M����,�kcas9�L���Ek[�f��3��랞�=pN2I�`�i���k�i�M��uBc�#���n���@rrFA�>�t�2y�|��c����׾G=r2x��xoW�M�i�5�O:[�yq$�vzu����Q-����Ok��[�Vk��V[���b�.n ��:�g T�*�*IB�)�rv�a��'�)6��vc�e9F��)4����z$��0��?��r8 ��1����3߸9�k�?�}/��oi�Ե�x�h��9��eS��!�����-tD�P��jw�}
```

Also the last echo with the img-tag doesn't appear in the html-dom.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*" name="pic">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" name="submit">
   </td>
  </tr
 </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
 $tmpName = basename($_FILES['pic']['name'];
 $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
 $donePic;
 convertImage($tmpName, $donePic, $size);
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($donePic).'"/>'; 
}
?>
```

Function convertImage

```
function convertImage($original, $output, $size) {
        //jpg, png, gif, bmp
        $ext = $size['mime'];

        if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext))
            $imageTemp = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);
        else if (preg_match('/png/i', $ext))
            $imageTemp = imagecreatefrompng($original);
        else if (preg_match('/gif/i', $ext))
            $imageTemp = imagecreatefromgif($original);
        else if (preg_match('/bmp/i', $ext))
            $imageTemp = imagecreatefromwbmp($original);
        else
            return 0;

        $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width / height
        if ($ratio > 1 ) {
            $width  = 300;
            $heigth = 300 / $ratio;
        } else {
            $width = 300*$ratio;
            $heigth = 300;
        }    

        $resizedImg = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $heigth);
        imagecopyresampled($resizedImg, $imageTemp, 0,0,0,0,$width, $heigth, $size[0], $size[1]);
        imagedestroy($imageTemp);

        imagejpeg($resizedImg, $output);
        imagedestroy($resizedImg);

        return 1;
    }
```

If you need any other information, feel free to ask me.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `$output` in `imagejpeg` is not what you think it is. It should be a string with a filepath or an open resource flux. If this value is null, the image flux is sent straight to the browser. Because your argument is a non-set var, it is understood as null and you get the last case, that's why you have this unexpected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of Kaddath. Thanks!

I had to change the code from

```
imagedestroy($imageTemp);
imagejpeg($resizedImg, $output);
imagedestroy($resizedImg);
```

to

```
imagedestroy($imageTemp);

//starting an output buffer to get the data
ob_start();

imagejpeg($resizedImg);

//here we get the data
$output = ob_get_clean();

imagedestroy($resizedImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formule for calcule ratio for new image is wrong. This is fixed:

```
if ($ratio > 1 ) {
    $width  = 300 * $ratio;
    $heigth = 300;
} else {
    $width = 300;
    $heigth = 300 / $ratio;
}
```

Comment: Actually both of you are wrong. You are calculating the image size with a **minimum** width of 300. @Schlodi is calculating the correct dimensions but he/she is swapping the dimensions. The formula should be `$width = 300 / $ratio` for `$ratio > 1` and `$height = 300 * $ratio` for `$ratio <= 1`. You can check that by the "units". Your `$width` in `$ratio > 1` has the "unit" `width²/height` instead of `width`.